# Joining on array postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Can someone please help me this, i have a blackout :)

DB postgres v 10.8

So i have two tables (Users and User_roles)

```
Select * from users where id = 1 

id       groups            username
1    ["read","admin"]        test

Select * from User_roles

id       name
1        write                     
2        read 
3        guest
4        admin
```

How can i make a join on the values in the array so my output will be:

```
username   user_id   user_roles_id  role
test          1          1          write
test          1          4          admin
```

Comment: Join on `unnest(groups)`

Comment: What is the datatype of that `groups` column? `text[]`, `jsonb`, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with s as 
    (select id,
     json_array_elements_text(groups::json) as role,
     username from users
     ) 
select s.username,
     s.id user_id,
     User_roles.id user_roles_id, 
     s.role from s inner join User_roles on(s.role=User_roles.name);
```

output

```
 username | user_id | user_roles_id | role
----------+---------+---------------+-------
 test     |       1 |             4 | admin
 test     |       1 |             2 | read
```

Comment: groups is a string ["read","admin"]

SQL Error [42809]: ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
  Position: 89

Comment: I changed the query please check

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
SELECT b.username,
       b.id   user_id,
       a.id   user_role_id,
       a.NAME role_name
FROM   user_roles a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                          Unnest(groups) nm,
                          username
                   FROM   users) b
               ON a.NAME = b.nm;
```

Output:

```
username | user_id | user_role_id | role_name
----------+---------+--------------+-----------
 test     |       1 |            4 | admin
 test     |       1 |            2 | read
```

**Edit**:
Earlier SQL was based on the assumption that data type of 'Group' was text[]. Seems the datatype is varchar() with row inserted this way.

```
postgres=# insert into users values(1, '["read","admin"]','test');
```

So,
Revised SQL:

```
SELECT b.username,
       b.id   user_id,
       a.id   user_role_id,
       a.NAME role_name
FROM   user_roles a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                          json_array_elements_text(groups::json) nm,
                          username
                   FROM   users) b
               ON a.NAME = b.nm;
```

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function unnest(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 77

Comment: The SQL was based on the assumption that data type of 'Group' was text[]. Changed the SQL.